# File details from a string in C#

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I have a string in C#

```
String file="\\mserver-80\docs\somedoc.doc"
```

Now How do I get fileInfo from the above sting.
What I mean is,
I want to declare something like

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(file);
fileExtn = fInfo.Extension;
```

Comment: Must be using a compiler that dispenses corporal punishment on build errors.

Comment: Buy a book on C# fundamentals ;-)

Comment: @Paul - Does that exist?  I want it! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# the string should be

```
String file="\\\\mserver-80\\docs\\somedoc.doc";
```

You can also escacpe the string using the @ character, which is a better alternative:

```
String file=@"\\mserver-80\docs\somedoc.doc";
```

other than that the code should work.

Comment: Good point. `@"\\mserver-80\docs\somedoc.doc"` will also work. However `\d` and `\s` will not compile, so it is easy to catch that error.

Comment: Good point Kobi, using @ is a better alternative. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can also try

```
Path.GetExtension(file)
```

Comment: This is a better solution than instatiating a FileInfo object if all you need is the extension.  If you'll be doing more than that, keep with the FileInfo, otherwise use this (I also believe the File static class has similar functionality, but I couldn't swear to that..._

Answer (score 4):

That code will work fine, using the [`FileInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

Simply add

```
using System.IO;
```

However, note that the `\` must be escaped as `\\`.
Instead, you should use an [`@""` string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx), like this:

```
String file = @"\\mserver-80\docs\somedoc.doc"
```